# Ubuntu issues after updating Ruby

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

I'm trying to install beef framework on my Ubuntu 14.04.

I'm getting the error :

```
Gem::InstallError: public_suffix requires Ruby version >= 2.0.
An error occurred while installing public_suffix (2.0.5), and
Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install public_suffix -v '2.0.5'` succeeds before
bundling.
```

I've tried to install ruby 2.4.0 and it worked and i used it using rvm :

```
root@XBuffer:/usr/share/beef-xss# rvm use ruby-2.4.0rvm 
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0
```

But I'm still getting the same error while using `bundle install`

I've tried even to manually install public_suffix :

```
root@XBuffer:/usr/share/beef-xss# gem install public_suffix -v '2.0.5'
Successfully installed public_suffix-2.0.5
Parsing documentation for public_suffix-2.0.5
Done installing documentation for public_suffix after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

But I still get the same exact error.

I'm really stuck at this and I've tried a lot of other solutions based on some researches.

Comment: It sounds like the commands `bundle` and `gem` are using different versions of Ruby. Could you post the result of running `which ruby` `which gem` and `which bundle` in the terminal?

Comment: `root@XBuffer:~/beef# which ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby`
`root@XBuffer:~/beef# which gem
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/gem`
`root@XBuffer:~/beef# which bundle
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@beef/bin/bundle`

@kcdragon

Comment: The bundle command looks like it's in a different directory. That's part of the problem.

Comment: 14.04 uses Ruby 1.9.3 so you cannot install it with the system ruby/gem/bundler. You then setup RVM for Ruby 2.4.0 and installed it using that. I don't see what the problem is here. Everything is happening as expected.